# Ember pagination jsonp callback api

Tags: api, ember.js, pagination, jsonp, ember-data

I have an API `example.com/api/v1`
and when navigate to `example.com/api/v1/items`

I got json data below.

```
[{
   "id":"1",
   "title":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
   "link":"/api/v1/items/1"
},
{
   "id":"2",
   "title":"consectetur adipisicing elit",
   "link":"/api/v1/items/2"
},
{
   "id":"3",
   "title":"sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt",
   "link":"/api/v1/items/3"
}]
.
.
.
```

This api accept parameter `offset`, `count`, and `callback`.

Ex: `example.com/api/v1/items?count=10` I will get

```
[{
   "id":"1",
   "title":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
   "link":"/api/v1/items/1"
},
.
.
.
{
   "id":"10",
   "title":"consectetur adipisicing elit",
   "link":"/api/v1/items/10"
}]
```

Ex: `example.com/api/v1/items?count=10&offset=10` I will get

```
[{
   "id":"11",
   "title":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
   "link":"/api/v1/items/11"
},
.
.
.
{
   "id":"20",
   "title":"consectetur adipisicing elit",
   "link":"/api/v1/items/20"
}]
```

How to implement pagination with ember?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

you could used [Ember-pagination](https://github.com/juanjardim/ember-pagination) where you only have to create and array like:

```
var Cities = CollectionArray.create({
    paginationSelector: "#cities-paging",
    itemsPerPage : 6
});
```

And then the library will do all the hard work for you including a typeahead box where your users could search for specific Items in the collection.
I hope that this can help you